# select an item from extjs combobox using python-selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, extjs, combobox

I have a extjs combobox with some items in it. I'm trying to select an item from the list..

```
**HTML Console steps** 

combo1 = document.getElementsByClassName('first-combo')[0]
input1 = combo1.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]
input1.click()
list1 = document.getElementsByClassName('x-boundlist')[0]
itemsArr = list1.getElementsByClassName('x-boundlist-item')
itemsArr.item(1).click()

** python steps**
combo1 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("first-combo")[0]
input1 = combo1.find_elements_by_tag_name("input")[0]
input1.click()
list1 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('x-boundlist')[0]
itemsArr  = list1.find_elements_by_class_name('x-boundlist-item')
itemsArr[1].click()
```

if I use the firebug console, first set of steps are perfectly selecting an item from combo box.
but the same steps in selenium-python throwing following error...
What I'm doing wrong here ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: itemsArr[1].click()
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Then `itemsArr` is length 0 or empty. Run the code in an interactive shell and check that it gets items.